# hive function to sql function conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I need help to convert the below Hive query into SQL query. I need to know how to convert unix timestamp functions into SQL.

```
SELECT 
    person_id, supervisor_id, assignment_type, primary_flag, 
    effective_start_date, effective_end_date,
    MAX(effective_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY p.person_id) AS max_effective_start_date
FROM 
    cg1_per_all_assignments_f p
WHERE 
    to_date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= COALESCE(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))), DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 1))
    AND to_date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= COALESCE(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))), DATE_ADD(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's functions:

```
Hive => Oracle:

to_date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) => sysdate 
DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 1) => sysdate -1
```

Comment: This conversion stands for mySql not for oracle sql